# Фоновое фиксированное видео

Tags: html, css

Я сделал вариант с фоновым видео с z-index где оно выходит из под предыдущего блока и скрывается следующим. Но задача сделать что бы следующий блок шел после блока с видео. То есть не перекрывал его, как в стандартной верстке где все position: relative и блоки идут просто по очереди. Из-за fixed на видео я не знаю как это сделать, не подскажете?

Песочница: https://jsfiddle.net/80rj18bq/2/

```css
body, div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}
.header {
  background: #ff0;
}
.footer {
  background: #f00;
}
.middleblockbg, .middleblockbg video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 700px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -50;
}
```

```html
<div class="header block"></div>
<div class="middleblock block">
  <div class="middleblockbg">
    <video autoplay loop muted>
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="footer block"></div>
```

Comment: То есть нужно сделать видео фиксированным внутри блока, но что бы это фиксирование не влияло на общую верстку. Это примерно как работает `background-attachment: fixed` нужен только для блока видео.

Comment: Так https://jsfiddle.net/80rj18bq/3/ ? Не совсем ясно, что именно вам нужно

Comment: @br3t не совсем. header должен быть поверх мидблока, но футер должен идти после него как в вашем варианте. Поверх означает что фон мидблока фиксирован и при скролле остается на месте, но все остальные блоки ведут себя как положено.

Comment: parallax эффект для видео фона, поищите в гугл, есть спец. плагины для этого, например http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/Responsive-Background-Video-Plugin-With-Parallax-Effect-backgroundVideo.html

Comment: @Elena оу, я задумывался об этом, а потом сбился мыслью что параллакс сам по себе не нужен. Да, это одно из решений.